# Encoding Tags for Random Forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, encoding

I have the following data set:
[image]

I want to use attributes **Tags** and **Authors** to classify each record into their respective **Rating**. In order to do so I want to use a **random forest** classifier. My concern is how to deal with **Tags** attribute. Each of the entry has an undetermined number of tags separated by a commas. There are a total of 4412 unique tags and the entry with more tags contains 20 tags. The first entry has tags ["Rhode Island","Economy", "Taxes", "Lincoln Chafee"].

How should I encode this attribute such that I can use [Random Forest Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) from sklearn?

Comment: Does this post answer your question ? [How can I fit categorical data types for random forest classification?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26283/how-can-i-fit-categorical-data-types-for-random-forest-classification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use sklearn [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html?highlight=multilabelbinarizer#sklearn-preprocessing-multilabelbinarizer)

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
lb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

lb.fit_transform([['A', 'B', 'C'],[ 'A', 'D', 'E', 'B']])
```

> **array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
>
> $\hspace{1cm}$ [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])**

2. If required, remove the columns below a threshold value (sum of the column). This will reduce the Features count by removing the low variance Features